# Can I hide some hosted zone from AWS IAM Users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-iam

Can I restrict my AWS IAM Users to list only selected hosted zones that I would like them to see using AWS IAM Policies?

Suppose I have three hosted zones A, B & C and I would like to hide A from my AWS IAM Users. What changes I need to do in this policy -

```
{
"Statement":[{
"Effect":"Allow",
"Action":["route53:GetHostedZone",
"route53:ListResourceRecordSets"],
"Resource":"arn:aws:route53::123456789012:change/*"
},
{
"Effect":"Allow",
"Action":,
"Resource":"*"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/YOURHOSTEDZONEID
```

where `YOURHOSTEDZONEID` is replaced with your hosted zone id.

Add each hosted zone as a separate resource to which your IAM users should be allowed access.

See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/364264/how-do-i-determine-the-arn-of-my-amazon-route53-hosted-zone